# Automatic service loading inside Controller using FOSElasticaBundle and Symfony 3.3

Tags: elasticsearch, symfony-3.3, foselasticabundle

Here's my autowiring configuration in `app/config/services.yml` : 
[image]

My controller :

[image]

Problem is when I use the new feature in Symfony 3.3 to automatically load service "`fos_elastica.index.app.cv`" in my bundle :
[image],
the container can no longer find the service inside the  `app/config/elastica.yml`.

[image]

Can you guys help me out to solve this problem, or if you have any clue on how can I read the service "`app/config/elastica.yml`" ?

Answer (score 1):

Struggled yesterday over the same problem while refactoring my controllers to services with autowire and injecting services in my controllers. 'fos_elstica.index.app.cv' can not autowired, so inject your dependency via constructor in your controller and configure your argument in service.yml. Place this at top of your controller:

```
private $finder;

/**
 * constructor.
 *
 * @param PaginatedFinderInterface $finder
 *
 */
public function __construct(PaginatedFinderInterface $finder)
{
    $this->finder = $finder;
}
```

In your services.yml:

```
AppBundle\Controller\MyContgroller:
    arguments:
        $finder: '@fos_elstica.index.app.cv'
```

Finaly use your finder in your action method via **$this->finder**.